# How come Node.js is faster when it only uses limited threads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I have been learning Node.js, but I have one question for which I cannot find answer anywhere. Here is what I get about Node.js=>

1. It is single-threaded in its architecture and uses CPU utilization efficiently due to its asynchronous non-blocking event-based looping.
2. How it executes these asynchronous requests is with the help of in-built library *libuv*, which uses threads(4 threads by default) in its internal thread pool. All these is kept away from "main" master thread which node.js uses. So we do not have to worry about that.

However, here is what my question - Suppose there are 100 asynchronous requests (let's say files) at once. Since the no. of threads *libuv* uses is limited, how exactly can node.js handle these 100 asynchronous requests at a time? It should ideally have 100 threads to handle these 100 asynchronous requests to respond the data back to the event queue quickly. How exactly is this faster than multi-threaded process?

Comment: Having 100 threads could actually hurt performance, since you probably don't have 100 CPU cores, and threads have their own overhead. Also more threads won't help if the bottleneck is something other than CPU, like transfer rate.

Comment: A file request doesn't use a thread afaik. It uses an asynchronous OS API itself.

Comment: @David784 okay let's keep the number to 8 threads. Then how exactly the node js apication that uses 4 threads(libuv) is better than an application that uses 8 threads?

Comment: @Bergi, which process handles the OS API? There must be something which processes this api and sends the result back to event queue?

Comment: For many types of requests (particularly I/O bound things which is the majority of web requests), the non-blocking, asynchronous, even-driven model can be way more efficient than a model where there is a new thread spawned for every incoming request.  This is because of the system overhead (RAM usage and wasted CPU) of creating and managing a lot of simultaneous threads (particularly when there are more active requests than cores).  Fully threaded models are also many times more complicated to program without concurrency bugs, often leading to lower developer productivity and more bugs.

Comment: @vkrp The libuv process does this. I gets notified by the OS of the IO event and puts it into the task queue. But there's only one process that handles this, not one thread per file operation.

Answer (score 0):

> How exactly is this faster than multi-threaded process?

The simple answer is, sometimes it isn't. No platform/language/compiler is best for every conceivable scenario.

However, sometimes it is faster. Dealing with many threads has its own problems (e.g. threads sharing CPU cores, thread deadlocking, race conditions, etc). In some cases node's approach is faster, because it doesn't have all that overhead to deal with those issues. In other cases it might not be faster.

That being said, there are things you can do (e.g. [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)) that can allow you to tailor node.js to your circumstances, if you find you are CPU limited. This is fairly common on web servers, to have as many worker threads as CPU cores. (or cores minus 1, to leave a core free for the OS etc)